# Creating a facebook application error

Tags: facebook

Is any one getting the following error "Sorry, an error has occurred. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can." when trying to create an facebook application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem, I also had some blank pages. Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and check under 'See my applications'. In the end it did in fact create the app, it just didn't tell me. (So I ended up with 20 applications after trying for a while). If the problem insists I suggest and try again later.

Answer (score 0):

That error comes for two reasons:

- Either facebook server is busy (rarely happens, try refreshing the page)
- You have an error in your code, the error will be their irrespective of refreshing the page unless you fix the error.